# Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded when running searchkick reindex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, rake, searchkick

First of all i have separated database according to the environment

```
group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

after adding few records. I ran the following reindex command in production.

```
bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Book
```

but it gives the following error

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its v                                                   ersion is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/book/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.                                                   rb:176:in `rescue in spec'
/book/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.                                                   rb:173:in `spec'
/book/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `establish_conne                                                   ction'
/book/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class                                                   :Railtie>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.16.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:404:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
/book/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:7:in `                                                   <top (required)>'
```

I appreciate any help as to why it is searching for sql although pg is set for production?

**UPDATE:**

Ok i solved the issue by doing Book.reindex in rails console production but i still want to know why

```
bundle exec rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Book
```

fails with the above error? It was working at the start. After making few upgrades like adding aws-sdk then it started showing the error. Could aws-sdk be breaking it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the adding `gem 'rails_12factor'` on production group

Gemfile

```
 group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
 end
```

Then

```
bundle install
bundle update
```

Then push to production and test it

Hope to help

Comment: ok please look above for update. i fixed the issue with running Book.reindex directly in console but still want to know why rake command is breaking with sqlite missing error.

Comment: i want to reduce the number of gems for production. can you tell what exactly the gem does and how does it solve the problem?